# can i use y-combinator to get object reference for this closure?

Tags: javascript, closures, y-combinator

this closure works:

```
var o = {
    foo: 5
};

o.handler = function(obj){
    return function() {
        alert(obj.foo);
    };
}(o);

o.handler(); //alert('5')
```

is it possible to define handler in-line, perhaps with something similar to a y-combinator operation?

```
var o = {
    foo: 5,
    handler: function(obj){
        return function() {
            alert(obj.foo);
        };
    }(o); //pointer to o? -----------------------------
};
```

out of academic curiosity, I'm not trying to do this in production code

[intro to the y-combinator](http://blog.jcoglan.com/2008/01/10/deriving-the-y-combinator/#)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible, because at the time of definition of the object literal, the variable `o` is undefined, and the `this` reference at the time of definition doesn't reference `o`.

If you used a temporary reference to `this` in the outer function and passed it into the closure, it would work, but you would not be able to pass in an object to get the `foo` property out of.

```
var o = {
    foo: 5,
    handler:function(){
        var self = this;
        return function() {
            alert(self.foo);
        };
    }
};

var h = o.handler();
h();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with an object literal *by itself*, as others have pointed out. However, the process can be wrapped. Wether or not it "adds anything" is debatable. This isn't the same as a Y-Combinator (perhaps half of it?), because it is not trying to give a "recursive name" (as far as I can tell Y-Combinators assume first-class functions and closures or a way to simulate such).

```
function bindMany (dict, res) {
  res = res || {}
  for (var k in dict) {
    if (dict.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      var v = dict[p]
      res[k] = v instanceof Function ? v(res) : v
    }
  }
  return res
}

var o = bindMany({
  foo: 5,
  handler: function(obj){
    return function() {
      alert(obj.foo)
    }
  }
})
```

Not-tested, but shows an approach that *could* be taken. There are subtle issues with this and a prototype chain on `dict`/`res`, if any -- an exercise for the reader.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the `this` keyword here:

```
var o = {
    foo: 5,
    handler: function() {
      alert(this.foo);
    }
};
```

That's a lot easier approach... Actually, your approach isn't even possible, as `o` is not defined when you refer to it.

Comment: But this isn't *strictly* the same as `this` may differ if `handler` is invoked upon a different receiver (or, say, passed as a callback).